# Doctrine 2: Force scheduleForUpdate on a non-changed entity

Tags: php, mysql, zend-framework, doctrine-orm

How can I schedule an entity for update, manually, when no property is actually changed?

I tried `$entityManager->getUnitOfWork()->scheduleForUpdate($entity)` but it gave an error in the core, and I have no intetion of debuging Doctrine.

The entity is managed if it matters: `$entity = $repository->findOne(1)`

I need this so doctrine would call my `EventSubscriber` on `flush()`.

I've also tried something like `$entityManager->getEventManager()->dispatchEvent(\Doctrine\ORM\Events::preUpdate)`, but then my listener's `preUpdate()` receives `EventArgs` instead of `PreUpdateEventArgs`.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is a bit hacky, but I was able to achieve this by doing something like the following.

```
$objectManager->getUnitOfWork()->setOriginalDocumentData($object, array('__fake_field'=>'1'));
```

This essentially causes Doctrine to think the document has changed from the original, and it computes it as a change which will cause the events to be executed on flush.

The example is for the MongoODM solution, but the same technique should work for ORM like below.

```
$objectManager->getUnitOfWork()->setOriginalEntityData($object, array('__fake_field'=>'1'));
```

Comment: I can't really test this now, but I'm pretty sure it will work as long as Doctrine does not make additional integrity checks. If it throws this next to the entity structure it will be removed and will make no difference. Can you confirm it worked for you?

Comment: I can confirm it worked for me.  I have implemented it in the tdm/doctrine-encrypt-bundle as well. [Packagist](https://packagist.org/packages/tdm/doctrine-encrypt-bundle) and [GitHub](https://github.com/TDMobility/DoctrineEncryptBundle).  Still working on documentation, but you know how it goes.

Answer (score 4):

Method mentioned by Wpigott not working for me (at least in doctrine/orm v2.4.2), instead I'm using this:

```
$entityManager->getUnitOfWork()->setOriginalEntityProperty(spl_object_hash($entity), 'field_name', '__fake_value__');
```

Where `field_name` existent property name.

Comment: For doctrine/orm 2.12 you need to use `spl_object_id()` instead of `spl_object_hash()`

Comment: Also you'll probably want to check if the entity is managed and only set the property if `$entityManager->getUnitOfWork()->isInIdentityMap( ... )` returns true, otherwise you'll get a "A managed+dirty entity ....  can not be scheduled for insertion" exception

Answer (score 2):

Even though this question is quite a bit old, I just found a way much more elegant to solve this problem I want to share here using Doctrine ORM 2.6.2:

You can simply tell the `ClassMetadataInfo` object of your table to just state those fields as dirty that you pass to the `propertyChanged` function of the `UnitOfWork`. The important parts here are the **setChangeTrackingPolicy** and **propertyChanged** calls:

```
$unitOfWork = $entityManager->getUnitOfWork();
$classMeta  = $entityManager->getClassMetadata('Your\Table\Class');
$ctp        = $classMeta->changeTrackingPolicy; # not a function but a variable

# Tell the table class to not automatically calculate changed values but just
# mark those fields as dirty that get passed to propertyChanged function
$classMeta->setChangeTrackingPolicy(ORM\ClassMetadataInfo::CHANGETRACKING_NOTIFY);

# tell the unit of work that an value has changed no matter if the value
# is actually different from the value already persistent
$oldValue = $entity->getValue('fieldName'); # some custom implementation or something
$newValue = $oldValue;
$unitOfWork->propertyChanged($entity, 'fieldName', $oldValue, $newValue);

# field value will be updated regardless of whether its PHP value has actually changed
$entityManager->flush();

# set the change tracking policy back to the previous value to not mess things up
$classMeta->setChangeTrackingPolicy($ctp);
```

You may also want to have a look at the `Doctrine\Common\NotifyPropertyChanged` interface.

I hope this will be useful for someone.

Answer (score 0):

What's the goal? If there is no property changed, why would you plan an update?

Comment: There is a legitimate reason to do this.  For example, if you have some listeners that modify the data before it is persisted and you need to do a migration.  This allows you to load and then flush each document and it will allow the listeners to change the data for persistance.  My use case is for encryption migration.  You can see it in https://github.com/TDMobility/DoctrineEncryptBundle

Comment: Another example: I do a cache on the response by the update time of the entity. I need to expire the cache not only when the entity is updated but also its related children. So it is a legitimate question. Not really like the answers though :)